# Assembly Language Multiplication

Tags: assembly, hex, multiplication

having a bit of trouble understanding assembly multiplication. Can anyone help break down the process of these steps:

```
mov  ax,[p1000]; p1000 = +1000    ax = 03e8
imul [n100];     n100 = -100
                 _____________
                      -100,000

dx:ax = fffe 7960   (dx = fffe, ax = 7960) cf = 1
```

I'm not sure how to deduce that the answer is -100,000 from dx:ax. I've tried calculating it like so:

dx = (15 * 16^3) + (15 * 16^2) + (15 * 16) + 14 = 65,534
ax = (7 * 16^3) + (9 * 16^2) + (6 * 16) = 31,072
dx + ax = 96,606

I may be approaching this the wrong way, so please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
imul [n100];
```

will multiply and leave the result in dx:ax

Now, dx:ax = fffe 7960. This is a 32 bit quantity with the upper 16bits in dx and the lower 16bits in ax. Since the the MSB of this overall 32bit **signed** quantity is 1, it's a negative number and we need the two's compliment to find magnitude.

```
FFFE 7960 <-- our number
0001 869F <-- 1's compliment in hex
0001 86A0 <-- 2's compliment in hex
...0001 1000 0110 1010 0000 <-- 2's compliment in binary
```

Convert that to decimal as usual (sum of all) (1*2^{bit_position}) ... we get the magnitude as ..

100,000.

Now recall that it's a negative signed number, (MSB = 1) so putting the sign and magnitude together we get ... -100,000 :)

Comment: Thanks! So what I should actually do is get the hex of +100,000 in 2's complement, convert it into its negative equivalent, and then sort that into dx and ax? Is the MSB simply the first non-zero digit we encounter from the left?

Comment: Registers are just bit-buckets. If an N-bit register holds a signed number, the MSB (most significant bit/left most bit/Nth bit) is the sign bit and N-1 bits are the magnitude part. If Sign=0, magnitude is read as is. If sign=1, magnitude is determined by 2's compliment as above. Don't worry about putting values into dx:ax or about format conversion; IMUL will automatically do that. Look at http://academic.evergreen.edu/projects/biophysics/technotes/program/2s_comp.htm for details

Answer (score 1):

In two's complement encoding, `0xfffe:7960` (a negative number since the topmost bit is set to 1) is `-(0x1:0000:0000-0xfffe:7960)` or `-0x1:86a0` which equates to `-100,000` in decimal.

You *don't* add the 16-bit `ax` and `dx` registers together to get the value, you treat them as a single 32-bit value.